# Construct a $C^\infty$ function that interpolates the identity and constant ones

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:** Does there exist a $C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (-1,0),$ $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(1,2)$, and $f$ is non-decreasing?

**Attempt:** Clearly with bump functions I can get a $C^\infty$ $f$ that satisfies $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (-1,0),$ $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(1,2)$. But the requirement that $f$ is non-decreasing makes my answer invaild.

Another way will be to start with a bump function $b(x)$ that equals $1$ on $(-1,0)$ and equals $0$ outside $[-1.5,0.5]$, and consider the integral $\int_0^x b(t)dt$. But this has $\int_0^x b(t)dt\neq0$ for $x\in(1,2)$.

Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: just let $f(x) = x$ on $(-\infty, 1)$ and $f(x)=1$ on $(1,\infty)$ and smoothly conjoin them at $x=1?$

Comment: what do you mean by "conjoin"?

Comment: @dezdichado - since your $f$ satisfies $f'(1-) = 1, f'(1+) = 0$, it cannot be smooth at $x = 1$. The reason that the behavior is unspecified on $[0,1]$ is exactly to give us room to make that transition smooth.

Comment: For your integration method, $\int_0^x b(t)\,dt = 1$ for $x \in (1,2)$, *exactly like it is supposed to.* Unfortunately, this isn't the solution. The problem calls for a $C^\infty$ function, but $\int_0^x b(t)\,dt$ is not even $C^1$. Also FYI, that is not a "bump function". Bump functions are *smooth*, non-negative, and $0$ outside some compact set.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Just fixed that typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $$h(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \le 0\\e^{-1/x}& 0 < x\end{cases}$$ 
Then let $$g(x) = a\int_0^xh(t)h(1-t)\,dt$$
choosing the constant $a$ so that $g(1) = 1$. Then

- as $h$ is $C^\infty$, so is $g$
- since for $t < 0, h(t) = 0, g \equiv 0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$.
- since for $t > 1, h(1-t) = 0, g \equiv 1$ on $[1,\infty)$.
- since $h \ge 0, g$ is non-decreasing.

Now define $$f(x) = xg(1-x) + g(x)$$
I'll leave showing $f' \ge 0$ everywhere to you (you don't need the exact form of $h$ to prove this - I just gave it as an example of how to build smooth functions).

Comment: Thanks! This kind of example is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I cut corners a bit at the end by simply noting that this particular combination was increasing. For different functions than just $x$ and $1$, it need not be. In that case, some additional manipulations would have been necessary.